# Angular is undefined in function

Tags: angularjs

for a variety of reasons, my company decided to follow this model for our various objects in Angular

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    function Principal($q, $http, $cookies) {
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$cookies = $cookies;
    }

    Principal.prototype.isIdentityResolved = function() {
        return angular.isDefined(this._identity);
    };

}());
```

The module is being defined by a master one level above this.

```
 var Principal = require('./Principal');
 var AuthServ = require('./AuthorizationService');

 var SecAng = angular.module('SecAng', []);

 SecAng.service('principal', Principal);
 SecAng.service('authorization', AuthServ);

 module.exports = SecAng;
```

and then browsify resolves that to a name and its included in my module in my app.js

My problem is the line `return angular.isDefined(this._identity);`.  I keep getting errors saying that angular is undefined.  Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Pass angular into your self-invoking function:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

   ...
}(angular));
```

Comment: got a plunker posted?

Comment: Ugh, no.  Not allowed to post to fiddle or plunker, corporate firewall won't let me.  corporate rules say im not allowed to post what i did, but i stripped the touchy stuff.